# Did the Ottoman Empire lose some control over Egypt during the Crimean War?

Tags: 19th-century, british-empire, egypt, ottoman-empire

What were the effects of the Crimean War on the relationship between the British and Ottoman empires? Did they lose partial control over Egypt?

Comment: This should possibly be three questions.

Comment: The last one definitely needs to be its own question. I'm tempted to edit it out of this one.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: I'm with @Luke. Take the last two bullets and make them each their own questions. Among other benefits, this may net you more total upvotes. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. Haha alright.

Comment: @T.E.D. I'm not sure... I feel like one answer would solve it all.

Comment: @DantheMan the Man They are related, but, Egypt becoming a colony then a protectorate / dominion, should be a question of its own, as it would require an answer that has sections totally unrelated to the other two.

Comment: yes, create the other two questions please..

Comment: One answer would not solve it all unless it was almost a term paper, even studying this in history class took a few weeks to cover all the ramifications.

Comment: Alright guys, I'll fix this in the morning.

Comment: Got it. done...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: no. Egypt formally became a British protectorate only in 1914, but *de facto* already in 1882. It's all (briefly) told [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khedive).

Answer (score 1):

The seeds of the Ottoman Empire's losing control over Egypt were sown during the [Crimean War](http://english.alarabiya.net/en/perspective/features/2014/03/03/Arab-involvement-in-Crimean-War-erased-from-history-.html). The Ottomans recalled their army from Egypt to fight in Crimea. Also, Egypt provided a small army for that war, that was demonstrably more modern (for the 19th century) than the Ottoman army.

And Egypt's first railroad was completed during the Crimean war. This, together with the war itself, led France to build the Suez Canal finishing in 1869 (Britain "bought in" in 1875). This extended their influence in Egypt, and reduced that of the Ottoman Empire.